# Plot[] generates erroneous values in a region for analytic expression

Tags: plotting, graphics

Mathematica 12.1

Something funny happening around t=750 for this non-periodic function.

```
w0 = 1;
w1 = Sqrt[0.55];
w2 = Sqrt[0.77];

Plot[ Sin[w0 t] + Sin[ w1 t] Sin[w2 t] , {t, 0.0, 1000.0}]
```

[image]

If you change the lower bound of domain, it's correct...

```
Plot[ Sin[w0 t] + Sin[ w1 t] Sin[w2 t] , {t, 1.0, 1000.0}]
```

[image]

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

w0 = 1;
w1 = Sqrt[55/100];
w2 = Sqrt[77/100];
```

Artifacts in plots can generally be reduced/eliminated by increasing [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and/or [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) and/or [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

```
Plot[Sin[w0 t] + Sin[w1 t] Sin[w2 t], {t, 0, 1000},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: yes PlotPoints will fix it, but what's strange is that there is nothing special going on in that region compared to other regions.

Comment: @Matthew, *you* know that, but the adaptive plotting capability can get fooled by very kinky plots like yours.